# Row width changes using button in twitter bootstrap table

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, twitter

I made a stupid typo when I typed this I put width instead of height!

I am using buttons in each row of a twitter bootstrap table. I am using table class table-condensed and button class btn-mini. The problem is that when I insert the button the HEIGHT of the row almost doubles. I cannot find what is causing this there appears to be no margin, padding or line-width specifically attached to the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="span3">
            <td class="span1">
                <button class="btn btn-mini">Button</button></td>
            <td class="span1">
                <button class="btn btn-mini">Button</button></td>

            <td class="span1">
                <button class="btn btn-mini">Button</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You can also ignore the class for each cell as it will divide the total span of the row according to the number of cells giving them equal widths.